# Circumscribed simple line arrangements are 3-colourable?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, graph-theory, coloring

UPDATE: Misha Lavrov (see comments) has convinced me this proposed solution is incorrect. I have shown there exist a $4-$colouring of $G$ in which $\partial(G)$  requires $3-$colours. However this result together with the knowledge that there exist a $3-$ colouring of $\overline{G}$ is not sufficient to show that $G$ is $3-$colourable. In particular just because "two-parts" of the graph require only $3$ colours this will not imply the whole graph requires only $3$ colours.

---

If $U$ is the unit disc centered at the origin consider $n$ chords drawn through the interior of $U$ such that no two chords are parallel and no three chords intersect at the same point. The arrangement graph $G$ induced by the discs and the chords has a vertex for each intersection point in the interior of $U$ and $2$ vertices for each chord incident to the boundary of $U.$ Naturally $G$ has an edge for each arc directly connecting two intersection points. $G$ is planar and $3-$connected.

---

> ***Question:*** Can we show that $\chi(G)=3$ ?

---

Proposed Solution (2019):

In this post the terms points and vertices are used interchangeably. As well as those of arcs and edges. I use $\chi()$ to denote the vertex colouring of a graph. All colourings are assumed to be proper. I write the following:

1. $\overline{G}$ - for the arrangement graph induced by the simple arrangement of chords drawn in the interior of $U.$ Note $\overline{G}$ does not have any edges incident to the boundary of $U.$
2. $\partial{G}$ - for the $2n$-cycle induced by the vertices and arcs along the boundary of $U.$
3. $G+x$ - for the one-point-extended graph of $G.$ That is a point $x$ which is exterior to the boundary of $U$ with a line drawn from every point on the boundary of $U$ to $x.$

Observe that $\chi(G)>2$ as $G$ contains $3-$cycles (or triangles). It is known that $\chi(\overline{G})=3.$ This fact was established by Felsner, Hurtado, Noy and Streinu in 2006 by way of wiring diagrams. It suffices to show that $\chi(\partial G)=3$ is order to establish that $G$ is $3-$colourable.

Consider $G+x.$ Observe that $G+x$ is planar and so by the $4-$colour theorem we have that $\chi(G+x)=4.$  If $\chi(\partial{G})=4$ then the point $x$ would have to be a colour that is different than any of the $4$ colours applied to the points on $\partial G.$ In particular $x$ would require a fifth colour and so $G+x$ would be $5$-colourable - a contradiction. And so $\chi(\partial{G})\leq 3$ and consequently $G$ is $3$-colourable. This completes the solution $\blacksquare.$

---

References:

1. William Tutte: [A Theorem on Planar Graphs](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5f29/a7c1647e76bf85dc6a821cf851d6fcdb13d4.pdf)
2. Robin Thomas: [4–CONNECTED PROJECTIVE-PLANAR GRAPHS ARE HAMILTONIAN](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d2a6/00261bce06804fc61da6152fc53cf6c23144.pdf)
3. Felsner, Hurtado, Noy and Streinu :[Hamiltonicity and Colorings of Arrangement Graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X06001831)

Comment: It is 2-colorable. Make the circle black. On each new chord flip the colors on one side of the chord, black to white and white to black.

Comment: How can it be 2-colourable if there are triangles?

Comment: I think point-colouring refers to the vertices while @CiaPan is probably referring to the faces ?

Comment: @TomCollinge: That's right, I meant faces. I've read the title and missed the 'point' in the question.

Comment: @TomCollinge I am asking for 3-colourability of the points, or if you like we can call them vertices. It does appear to be Face 2-colourable - excluding the infinite unbounded face.

Comment: I don't believe the current solution. In general, if two parts of a graph are $3$-colorable, then that doesn't mean the whole graph is $3$-colorable. If $\partial G$ is a $2n$-cycle, then $\chi(\partial G)=2$. Your argument with the external vertex shows that there is a $4$-coloring of $G$ that uses only $3$ colors on $\partial G$, but that doesn't mean that $\chi(G)=3$. (However, the "wiring diagram" argument, which can also be phrased as a greedy coloring when we order vertices by $x$-coordinate, shows that $G$ except for possibly one boundary vertex can be colored with $3$ colors.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov this is incorrect. And even if it was $2$-colourable the graph $G$ would still require only $3$. On the other hand a $2n-$cycle should require only $2$ colours. Where is my thinking wrong ?

Comment: @AntonioHernandezMaquivar My main objection is this: in general, if two parts of a graph are 3-colorable, then that doesn't mean the whole graph is 3-colorable.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I follow you and I now understand your point.

Comment: I think that in general it is hard to make arguments based on gluing together two parts of $G$ work. A more promising direction is maybe extending the wiring diagram argument. (By the way, Conjecture 2 in the Felsner et al. paper implies that this graph is $3$-colorable.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov in the opposite direction a solution to my colouring problem implies the conjecture concerning great circles - via stereographic projection ? In particular the point-edge incident relation of $G$ is preserved under a stereographic map and so the colouring.